# Erro ao instalar biblioteca de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

Estou com um problema ao tentar instalar a biblioteca `pyaudio` no Windows. Aparece o seguinte resultado:

> Command
>   "c:\users\digia\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\digia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cdsxn7hr\PyAudio\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\digia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-cyh5ewvi\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\digia\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cdsxn7hr\PyAudio\

O que faço?

Comment: Quais comandos executou para chegar neste erro? Em qual diretório? Onde baixou a biblioteca?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai ter que baixar o instalador e instalar manualmente, infelizmente o windows não da suporte a muitas libs do python, eu recomendo fortemente usar sistemas baseados em linux, mais para solucionar o seu problema, baixe e instale isso:

https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

e tente importar em seus projetos